# Android SQLite: displaying data entries

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I have been trying to work out the bug on this but can't seem to find what I'm looking for search Google for the past few days, i have hit and missed on stuff that is leaning towards what i want to do but haven't ran across anything that is what i am trying to do.

To start off, I built my SQLite DB along with "TheNewBoston Android Tuts" everything works fine, now that I am trying to change the view database around it errors out or crashes the app at start up. I am wanting to display certain columns in a row from the DB with the Cursor using the for loop and to dynamically load the TableView with the data:

DbEntry[ data | data| Displayed | data | Display | Display | data ]

I can do this if i have a TextView off on its own but with it in a TableLayout>TableRow i think that's where the problem is but not sure... would like to be able to load the table rows from the class its self instead of setting the text views if possible. I hope i gave enough info on what i am trying to do, if anyone can point me to a really good tutorial or give some light on this, it wold be greatly appreciated.

XML:

```
 <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/view_Table"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="5" >
 <TableRow   
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4" >
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/view_DbCol3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="DB Col 3 Displayed Data" />
        </TableRow>
```

with xml i hope i am doing the table right that its similar to hmtl  kind of things by putting table rows in side one another

SQLview Class

```
setContentView(R.layout.sqlview);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view_DbCol3);
    try {
        DBload info = new DBload(this);
        info.open();
        String data = info.getData();
        info.close();
        tv.setText(data);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Error Message Dialog
        String error = e.getLocalizedMessage();
        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
        d.setTitle("DB ERROR");
        TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
        tv1.setText(error);
        d.setContentView(tv1);
        d.show();
    }
```

DbHelper Class: getData Method

```
public String getData() {

    String[] cols = new String[] {KEY_PLACE}; 
                 // I have also tried with all my KEY variables

    // reads info from DB columns
    Cursor c = ourDB.query(KEY_TABLE, cols, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int Ione = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PLACE);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        result = result 
        + c.getString(Ione) 
        + "\n";
    }
    return result;
}
```

the error i am getting is

> 11-17 00:13:09.993: E/CursorWindow(590): Bad request for field slot 0,-1. numRows = 2, numColumns = 1

like i said i hope i have given enough information for little help if possible, thanks alot

Comment: just use listview ... find example in sdk folder ...  NotePad project or List7.java in ApiDemos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842) will help you alot.

anywayz try this in you code

```
if(c.getCount()>0) {
    int index=0;
    while(c.moveToNext()){

    result = result  
            + c.getString(index)  
            + "\n"; `enter code here`
    index++;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: you need to change the variable name of c as you define with integer data type while c is already in used with Cursor datatype

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to say that your column 'KEY_PLACE' doesn't exists, because the columnIndex method returns -1.

Check the value of KEY_PLACE and the name of the column returned in your cursor

Hope it helps
Jokahero

PS: You should check that your cursor is not null before using it:

```
if (c != null) {
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And also don't forget to close your cursor when the job is finished:

```
c.close();
```

Comment: thanks alot,,, that helped out alot ,, the other two guys got me to think down along the line of the if statement couldn't get my finger on it.. but that fix what ever glitch was going on though... thanks alot for the help